# SQL Insert Into Select with Openquery on Linked Servers getting Clr Types are not allowed in distributed queries error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to send data from one server to another using linked servers. This works fine for most of the tables I am trying to copy.

```
Insert into [Server1].[database1].[dbo].[tableName]
([OriginID],[Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[CopyDate])
    SELECT @MyID,
    [Column1],
    [Column2],
    [Column3],
    [Column4],
    GetDate())
FROM [Server2].[database2].[dbo].[tableName] sourceTableName
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM[Server1].[database1].[dbo].[tableName] destTableName
WHERE destTableName.OriginId= @MyId AND destTableName.value = sourceTableName.value;
```

However, it does not work for tables with CLR types. For that I tried to use OPENQUERY using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY([Server1], 'SELECT [OriginID],[Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[CopyDate]')

([OriginID],[Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[CopyDate])

SELECT 100,[Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[CopyDate], GetDate()
FROM OPENQUERY([Server2], 'SELECT 100,[Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],[CopyDate], GetDate() FROM [Database2].[dbo].[tableName] sourceTableName')

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM[Server1].[database1].[dbo].[tableName] destTableName
WHERE destTableName.OriginId= @MyId AND destTableName.value = sourceTableName.value;
```

However, I am still getting the error

> objects exposing columns with CLR types are not allowed in distributed
>   queries. Please use a pass-through query to access remote object
>   `[database1].[dbo].[tableName]`

I have tried various versions of this, but nothing works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *However, it does not work for tables with CLR types* ... can you post the exact error for first block like you do for second code block?

Comment: The exact same error

Comment: Please show the  column schema of both tables: `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'`